# Find the limit $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2n^4+1}} + \frac{2}{\sqrt{2n^4+2}} + \cdots + \frac{n}{\sqrt{2n^4+n}}\right)$.

Tags: calculus, limits

Is there any smart trick to find the following limit?
$$
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2n^4+1}} + \frac{2}{\sqrt{2n^4+2}} + \cdots + \frac{n}{\sqrt{2n^4+n}}\right).
$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$\lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2n^4}}\sum_{k=1}^{n}k = \lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{n(n+1)}{2\sqrt{2}\,n^2}=\color{red}{\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}}.$$
We get the same limit if we replace the initial $\sqrt{2n^4}$ with $\sqrt{2n^4+n}$. 
It follows that our actual limit also equals $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}$.

Comment: +1. Your shortcut avoids the $Hurwitz\ Zeta\ Function$. Clever.